# PHP wont read past backslash (addslashes())

Tags: php, mysql, string, post

I am having trouble with getting PHP to read the whole string.

I currently have...

```
<input type="text" name="example" value="My name's Simon" />
```

I have added `addslashes($_POST['example'])`

However when I `echo` to check the output it only reads `"My name\"` and then will not read any more. Can anyone help with this?

I am using it to update a row in MySQL and obviously if the input is not matching, it is not updating the table. How can I get it to read the whole string after the backslash?

(The code currently works fine and updates the table correctly when there is no single quotes/apostrophe).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should look into using PDO. It saves the headache of having to escape your query strings.

Comment: echo htmlentities($_POST['example'])

Comment: use mysqli prepared statement for query ...

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, much appreciated. I am still struggling to get i to read past the backslash. I will have a look at PDO and see if I can find a solution. Thanks again!